# Need to find the intersection point of two line segments iterated over multiple segments

Tags: python, line-intersection

OK, here is the problem. I am trying to calculate the intersection of two lines by comparing multiple line segments that are read out of a series of csv files. I've already got the x,y coordinate pairs for each line segment into a list of tuples within tuples as follows:

```
continuousLine = [((x1,y1),(x2,y2)), ...]
crossingLines = [((x1,y1),(x2,y2)), ...]
```

[Line Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu0LQ.png)

I am trying to figure out how to iterate along the continuous line and through the crossing lines to find out where along the continuous line each crossing line intersects.

Basically I want (pseudo-code listed below):

```
for segment in continuousLine:
    if segment in crossingLines intersect == True:
       return intersection
    else:
       move on to next crossing line segment and repeat test
```

I hate asking for help on this because I am too new to coding to help other people, but hopefully someone can work through this with me.

I do have a method that I think will work to calculate the intersection once I've figured out the iterator:

```
line1 = ()
line2 = ()
def line_intersection(line1, line2):
    xdiff = (line1[0][0] - line1[1][0], line2[0][0] - line2[1][0])
    ydiff = (line1[0][1] - line1[1][1], line2[0][1] - line2[1][1]) #Typo was here

    def det(a, b):
        return a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0]

    div = det(xdiff, ydiff)
    if div == 0:
       raise Exception('lines do not intersect')

    d = (det(*line1), det(*line2))
    x = det(d, xdiff) / div
    y = det(d, ydiff) / div
    return x, y

print line_intersection((A, B), (C, D))
```

Comment: Do you know how to determine the intersection point of two lines, given their end points? If so, [edit] your question and add that.

Comment: I do, thanks for the suggestion and see the post edit above.

Comment: Jolly good—you can see you got a few answers as a result. BTW, I suggest you `raise` a less generic exception, perhaps something specific like `ValueError('lines do not intersect')` because a generic one can hide many other issues (like `SyntaxError` or `KeyboardInterrupt`) which can make code development more difficult, since the caller will have to `except Exception:` to handle cases that don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't provided any sample input and expected output, I'm going to use the dummy version of the `line_intersection()` function shown below. All it does is print its input and returns a hardcoded result — but it will show you how to iterate through the input data and pass it to the real function.

It should be clear from the output what it's doing.

```
def line_intersection(line1, line2):
    print('intersecting:')
    print('  ({}. {}), ({}, {})'.format(line1[0][0], line1[0][1],
                                        line1[1][0], line1[1][1]))
    print('  ({}. {}), ({}, {})'.format(line2[0][0], line2[0][1],
                                        line2[1][0], line2[1][1]))
    print('')
    return 100, 200
```

All the looping has been put in a generator function named `find_intersections()` which returns successive intersections it finds, skipping any combinations that don't.

```
def find_intersections(continuous_line, crossing_lines):
    for cl_segment in continuous_line:
        for xl_segment in crossing_lines:
            try:
                x, y = line_intersection(cl_segment, xl_segment)
            except Exception:
                pass
            else:
                yield x, y
```

Here's a usage example with made-up input data:

```
continuous_line = [((1,2),(3,4)), ((5,6),(7,8)), ((9,10),(11,12))]
crossing_lines = [((21,22),(23,24)), ((25,26),(27,28)), ((29,30),(31,32))]
intersections = [(x, y) for x, y in
                    find_intersections(continuous_line, crossing_lines)]
print('intersections found:')
print(intersections)
```

Output:

```
intersecting:
  (1. 2), (3, 4)
  (21. 22), (23, 24)

intersecting:
  (1. 2), (3, 4)
  (25. 26), (27, 28)

intersecting:
  (1. 2), (3, 4)
  (29. 30), (31, 32)

intersecting:
  (5. 6), (7, 8)
  (21. 22), (23, 24)

intersecting:
  (5. 6), (7, 8)
  (25. 26), (27, 28)

intersecting:
  (5. 6), (7, 8)
  (29. 30), (31, 32)

intersecting:
  (9. 10), (11, 12)
  (21. 22), (23, 24)

intersecting:
  (9. 10), (11, 12)
  (25. 26), (27, 28)

intersecting:
  (9. 10), (11, 12)
  (29. 30), (31, 32)

intersections found:
[(100, 200), (100, 200), (100, 200), (100, 200), (100, 200), (100, 200), (100,
200), (100, 200), (100, 200)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the function `line_intersection` would return False on `div == 0` instead of raising exeption.

**The easy way:**

```
filter(None, [intersection(a, b) for a in continuousLine for b in crossingLines])
```

However, using nested loop, it is slow when there are lots of segments in crossingLines.

**A more efficient way:**

To improve performance, have a try on [intervaltree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intervaltree), which will give you the intersect candidates for testing. In your case, first build a interval tree on crossingLines, then loop through continuousLine to find intersect candidates in that tree, and test to get the final result.